# How to get video thumbnail for starting duration in android?

Tags: android, sd-card, android-videoview, video-thumbnails

I want to display video thumbnail from sdcard video i have tried one code for display video thumbnail but it is display thumbnail lastduration i want to display thumbnail when first screen display when video start.

What i have tried check below.

```
Bitmap bitmap = ThumbnailUtils.createVideoThumbnail("/mnt/sdcard/peakmedia/201411200944130359.mp4",
                                            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MINI_KIND);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this code will help you :

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(String file_path);
Bitmap bmpCover = retriever.getFrameAtTime(0,  MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```

Comment: still display same thumbnail

Comment: suppose if we display video for alphabet like a to z than a is display when video start so i want thumbnail when video start and display first whatever

Comment: sry dude, i can't get your question properly

Comment: when video will start whatever the play i want to display that in imageview